# Isolation level strategy for asp.net and sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

What should be ideal Isolation level strategy for asp.net and sql server 2008. We use read-commited but it still hangs see ex below.

- Table name - `Customers`
- Isolation level - `Read Committed`

Transaction 1:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed
Begin Tran

UPDATE Customers
SET ordercount = 50 
WHERE id = 2

WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:20'
rollback tran
```

Transaction 2:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed
Begin Tran

Select * From Customers 

Trans commited
```

Transaction 2 hangs for 20 second!! How to handle this scenario?

Regards,

Chandan

Comment: Yes - of course - if you update some rows in `Customers` and you wait for 20 seconds in that transaction - you cannot read all those rows (that are being updated) until that first transaction finishes. That's my it's so important to keep your transactions **short!**

Comment: So what behavior do you want to happen? Read the "before" version of the `id = 2` row? Read the "after" version that may never be committed? Skip reading that row entirely? All of them are possible.